# Install "Media Feature Pack" on Windows 2009 (20H2) - OFFLINE

Tags: windows-10, dism, wsus-offline

I am trying to figure out if it's possible to install the Windows Media Feature Pack on a Windows 10 N computer, build 20H2 whilst being offline.

For versions of Windows 1903 and below you could download the Media Feature Pack as an .msu file and install onto a PC without it being connected to the Internet.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack

From build 1909 onwards you are required to install the Media Feature Pack from Settings > Apps > Apps and Features > Optional Features > Add a Feature.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/media-feature-pack-for-windows-10-n-november-2019-aaf0e378-8828-78d9-b91d-e378f82f252c

I thought the feature may have been included as part of the Feature On Demand (FOD) ISO, but the Media Feature Pack is not listed in the following article.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/features-on-demand-non-language-fod

I also tried setting "The Specify settings for optional component installation and component repair" policy on the client, and as described in the URL below configured the "Alternate source file path" to point to a Windows 10 (non-N) WIM file.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/fod-and-lang-packs

[image: Optional component installation GPO]

I have also tried to install using Powershell, pointing to the content from the FOD ISO and a Windows SXS folder from a non-N version of Windows.

```
  Add-WindowsCapability -Name Media.MediaFeaturePack~~~~0.0.1.0 -Online -LimitAccess -Source \\Server\Share$\FOD

  Add-WindowsCapability -Name Media.MediaFeaturePack~~~~0.0.1.0 -Online -LimitAccess -Source \\Server\Share$\WinSXS
```

Please can somebody help me understand if this is in fact possible and if so how to do it.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: This M$' strive to turn windows machines into thin clients totally dependent on internet connection is plain enfuriating!..

Comment: were you able to accomplish your task with the offline installation?